# Switch between two languages for spell checking in Google Chrome for Mac

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, osx-lion, spell-check

Environment: Mac OS X 10.7.2, Chrome 15.

This is how `chrome://settings/languages` looks like:

[image: languages]

When I right click on a text box and go to **Spell-checker Options**, I get a lot of languages there, but not Croatian.

[image: options]

If at `chrome://settings/languages` I click **Use this language for spell checking** for Croatian, then it appears at **Spell-checker Options**.

[image: croatian]

But if I switch back to English at **Spell-checker Options**, Croatian disappears.

[image: options]

I would like to be able to switch between English and Croatian, but I do not know how to set it up.

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen in the implementation of `SpellCheckHost::GetSpellCheckLanguages(...)`, which is called [when the menu is initialized](http://codesearch.google.com/#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/tab_contents/spellchecker_submenu_observer_hunspell.cc&l=51), Chrome/Chromium first [adds the currently selected spell-checking language](http://codesearch.google.com/#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/spellchecker/spellcheck_host.cc&l=56) to the list of spell-checking languages, and then iterates over the [languages available for spell-checking in Mac OS X](http://codesearch.google.com/#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/spellchecker/spellcheck_host.cc&l=64) ([implementation here](http://codesearch.google.com/#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/spellchecker/spellcheck_platform_mac.mm&l=169)).

Croatian is not one of the latter, as can be seen e.g. in the spell-checking options in *Pages*:

> [image]

---

Which languages are enabled for spell-checking on the UI is provided is determined by line 402 [here](http://codesearch.google.com/#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/resources/options/language_options.js&l=402&q=spellCheckLanguageCodeSet&exact_package=chromium&type=cs), which is ultimately provided with data from [here](http://codesearch.google.com/#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/common/spellcheck_common.cc&l=17&type=cs).

So the issue here is that the two parts of the UI (spell-check context menu and languages selection in preferences) are using two different sets of spell-checkers to determine which languages are supported.

---

Using that menu to change the language removes it from the list. Unless you're willing to compile your own browser, or file a bug against Chrome on OS X, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping compiling the browser would not be necessary. :)

Comment: @ŽeljkoFilipin Well, you can always file a bug with the developers. I might have provided you enough information to write a useful report, at least.